# How do I control overflowing content in html page printing?

Tags: javascript, css, vue.js

! My Problem Images (https://eksiup.com/p/jv228194htuw)
I'm preparing a printable test project, but when the page content is long, I want the related question to go to the next page under my header section How can I do this?

Answer (score 0):

You can use CSS styling and apply it only to print.
Here is an example:

```
@media print {
#header {
margin-top: 100px;
}}
```

That CSS renders the `#header` to have a margin top of 100px but only on print.

If you want to remove the header on print use this:

```
@media print {
#header {
display: none;
}}
```

Comment: !  Result Image (https://eksiup.com/p/fa228282d2as)

this is what I get when I apply what you say. But this is not what I want

Comment: In the images that you are sending us: How are we supposed to know which element you want to move and where? Also, how are we supposed to know which element has which class/code to target?
Your images don't help. Therefore please help yourself by helping us first and share proper code and links. Don't expect magic by someone looking at an image.

Comment: First Image (https://eksiup.com/p/xo228334dgzp)
ok then let me tell you with the pictures that I want to print the contents of the first page I get the image
Second Image (https://imgyukle.com/i/2.Eoxuvv)

this is the image on page 2, but the relevant content does not appear because of the header I want to make the contents of the header below the show

Comment: So basically what you are asking is to remove the header on print? Is that correct? If yes, I edited my answer.

Comment: no when printing my content is left behind the header and the content does not appear, I want to show my content under the header on the other pages in the print as in the first image.But 2.3.4 ..... the content on the other pages remains under the header

Answer (score 0):

After reading your comments now I understand you want to force an element onto the next page only for print. Since we don't know what class your element has because you didn't provide any links. We will give you general code which you will have to modify.

This is the CSS you would use if you wanted an element to be on the next page:

```
@media print {
.ThisIsYourElement {
page-break-after: always;
}}
```

Here is the [documentation](https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_print_pageba.asp) for that.

Comment: Well, I have a component called my card. This component is left under the component header in the 2nd or 3rd pages and I don't see my content.

Myheader Element id=header

MyComponent  inclusive div id=myCompDiv

Comment: First of all; your header is not useful for print. It shows no good information for print. Therefore remove it from print with the code I gave you in my other answer. And secondly; we can't give you the exact code because you didn't give us the exact link or code.

Comment: ! (https://imgyukle.com/i/3.EojqEx) My Problem Image.

overflowing from the page header and I can't see my content overflowing from the page I want to show my content under the header

Comment: If your header is covering the content. Then delete your header on print only. The code for that was already given to you.

Comment: I know, but I need a title on each page, and my content needs to appear under the title like on page 1

Comment: It's not possible to give you anymore codes because we don't know what classes your elements have.